# Pullback of the differential form $\alpha = dz + \sum_ix^idy^i$ via $f$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

On $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ use coordinates $z,x^1,y^1,...,x^n,y^n$. Let $\alpha = dz + \sum_ix^idy^i$. I wanted to compute the pull back $f^*\alpha$ for $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ with $f(z,x^1,...,y^n) = (t^2z,tx^1,...,ty^n)$.

Unfortunately, i'm not sure whether my attempt is going in the right direction.

**My attempt:**

\begin{align*}f^*\alpha = f^*\left(dz + \sum_ix^idy^i\right) = d(t^2z) + \sum_i tx^i d(ty^i)& = 2tzdt+t^2dz + \sum_i tx^i (y^idt+tdy^i) \\ &=  2tzdt+t^2dz +  \sum_itx^iy^idt + \sum_itx^itdy^i \\ &= t(2zdt+tdz )+t\left( \sum_ix^iy^idt + \sum_ix^itdy^i\right)
\end{align*}

would this be reasonable so far? Am I on the right track? Or did i do something fundamentally wrong?
Any help is appreciated. I'm not entirely sure how to further simply and thus would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: $t$ is not a coordinate, it's a constant/scaling factor. So there should be no $dt$ terms. Apart from that, it looks good.

Comment: thanks for the comment @user17945. I wasn't sure about $t$, however, i remember that in the case of a coordinate transformation into spherical coordinates, we also considered the radius $r$ and differentiated with respect to it. So i thought this would be the same here.

Comment: You say yourself that the coordinates $z, x^1,y^1,\ldots, x^n,y^n$ - no $t$. Notice that your pulled back form seems to depend on $2n+2$ coordinates, although it's a form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

Comment: Then $f^*\alpha$ would become $t^2dz+\sum_itx^itdy^i = t^2dz+\sum_it^2x^idy^i = t^2\left(dz +\sum_ix^idy^i\right)$ which looks pretty good. Thank you very much, highly appreciating your help.

Comment: That looks correct. Glad it helped.